# Instantiate of wrapper class in lightning Controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I have a Wrapper class, which I need to instantiate in my Aura Controller.
I'm not able to understand how can I instantiate it in my controller

Wrapper Class:

```
public class CustomWrapper {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public Account acc {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Contact> conList{get;set;}
    
    public CustomWrapper(){
        acc = new Account();
        conList = new List<Contact>();
    }
    
}
```

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="wrapper" type="CustomWrapper[]" default="[]"/>
```

Controller:

```
var RowItemList = component.get("v.wrapper");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already defaulted it to `default="[]"`. So it is instantiated to a blank array.

Either you need to create object in the `JS` and again pass that to backend, or define your default as : I have written `sobjectType` property just to show an example, you can fill in your Account object property and that should work fine.

`default='[{"conList":[{"sobjectType":"Contact","LastName":""}],"acc":{"sobjectType":"Account","Name":""}}]'/>`

Which will make your attribute as :

```
<aura:attribute name="wrapper" type="CustomWrapper[]" default='[{"conList":[{"sobjectType":"Contact","LastName":""}],"acc":{"sobjectType":"Account","Name":""}}]'/>
```

Then when you do `JSON.parse(cmp.get("v.wrapper"))` you will get a object where you can fill in the value.

Or you can even create an `enqueuaction` to return your instantiated fields.

```
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static List<CustomWrapper> instantiateCW() {
    List<CustomWrapper> lstCustomWrappers = new List<CustomWrapper>();
    lstCustomWrappers.add(new CustomWrapper());
    return lstCustomWrappers;
}
```

and in your `doInit` do this:

```
let action = cmp.get('c.instantiateCW');
action.setCallback(this,function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        cmp.set('v.wrapper', response.getReturnValue());
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Issue in this is it eats up your enqueue action queue and moreover you will have to be careful in using the `v.wrapper` attribute as it will be set in `callback` which means you will have to write your code in such a way that whereever you are using `v.wrapper` it should be called after `action` is finished.